# Why is my Gif file created by PIL so large?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gif

I used Python's PIL(Pillow) to create more than 100 images, when I save these images separately as JPEG files, each take about 10KB.

```
im.save("frame%d.jpg" % idx, "JPEG")
```

But if I merge these images into a Gif file, the file takes close to 20MB!

```
# sequence is list of all images [im1, im2 ...]
gif = Image.new("P", (w, h))
gif.save("result.gif", save_all=True, append_images=sequence, duration=100, optimize=True) # 10fps
```

Why is this? And how could I compress the gif file to take much less space?

Comment: Is each image a frame? How big is it in pixels?

Comment: What's surprising? Jpeg is lossy compression, gif is lossless compression. You only can tune pixel-size and color-range then (and to some extent internal entropy for better losless-compression).

Comment: Also, dithering 24 bit JPEG data to 8 bit palette mapped GIF data often makes the image data much less compressible, and GIF's lossless compression algorithm is somewhat simpler than JPEG's lossy one.

Comment: 400x300 px. I know tools like GIMP can take a gif and compress it, so that only the difference between frames are saved, what is the algorithm to do that?

Comment: GIF has no real support for inter-frame compression. What you refer to sounds like some hacky-stuff with alpha-channels. Try GIMPs stuff on your images. I don't think it will work well with photo-like images. (GIF is an outdated format missing tons of moden features and only lives because it's supported everywhere)

Comment: also you should filter out the JPG noise before compression o use PNG instead of JPG ...